# How many personal computers have Java installed?

Tags: java, jvm

Are there any published data on the availability of a Java runtime on PCs?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Around 85%, [according to this.](http://www.w3resource.com/browsers/java-support.php) [RIAstats](http://riastats.com/) used to provide more info on how they collected stats, but they appear to be defunct.

Comment: There's something strange. According to that website, 3.02% have Java version 1.8 (?!) installed? What's that? The current version of Sun Java is version 6 (or 1.6).

Comment: I wondered about that too; I think maybe they mean 1.1.8, which is the last release of "Java 1.0".

Comment: +1 for the link. Gives the bean counters something to chew on should I ever need to make an argument about what technology to support. I still question statistics harvested from the Internet however. Browser penetration numbers I've seen don't come anywhere close to the actual usage on our corporate website due to our audience.

Comment: Dead link :( I wish there was something simillar but functional.

Comment: This is why you shouldn't just answer with a link, but make a small summary of the data you find. The site is dead and the answer is void.

Comment: @Konerak The data is constantly changing, so any quote will soon be out of date. That's one of the reasons this question is off-topic for StackOverflow.

Answer (score 4):

It's not a published report, but here is one data point. According to the stats (Google Analytics) on my website, 90% of visitors have Java.

Comment: Of those remaining 10%, what devices are they using (phones by any chance)?

Comment: 98% are Windows, Linux, Mac. They may have java installed and have it disabled in their browser.

Comment: The Google Analytics stat is JAVASCRIPT not Java.  Very different things.

Comment: No, it's Java. Users that don't have Javascript don't even show up in Google Analytics.

Comment: My sites has about the same percentage.

Answer (score 2):

Acording to wikipedia:

> According to Sun, the Java Runtime Environment is found on over 700 million PCs

[Wikipedia link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_(software_platform))

**EDITED**:

Since you are asking for a percentage, if we consider that there are aprox. 1 Billion of PC in the world ([wikipedia again](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Personal_computer#Market_and_sales) it's a 70%.

Comment: That's not a percentage. Statistics will probably work better here than a head count...

Answer (score 0):

dont forget java on embedded devices

Comment: At a recent UK Java Event James Gosling stated that the average Londoner has three JVMs on their person: One in their mobile phone, one in their SIM card, and another in their Oyster Card (travel-pass).

Comment: Most JavaCards run precompiled programs - they have no interpreter, so calling it a JVM implementation is a bit of a push.