# Java usage and deployment for Windows 2013

Tags: java

I develop java applications sometimes. If I distribute my application in a jar archive and makes a simple wrapper so that it can have custom icon and the user do not need to run the application like "java -jar ...". How likely is it that my potential user have java jre installed if its a Windows user?

In other words: How many percent of windows users have java installed?

Comment: If you want to run any kind of Java application you will need to have a JRE installed.   If you really need stats, see...
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1297806/how-many-personal-computers-have-java-installed

Comment: Unfortunately, the answer seems to be that there is no credible source of information on this at the moment.

Comment: i*io*s, its 4 years old.... dont rate me down and link to none valid answers

Comment: common... http://www.riastats.com/ do not even exists anymore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are som statistics from 2010: http://secbrowsing.blogspot.sk/2010/09/top-browser-plugins-and-more-statistics.html

38% Java(TM) Platform SE 6 U21

28% Java Deployment Toolkit 6.0.210.7

In one browser both plugins can be installed. Try to find better Java plugin statistic and you have better numbers. Cheers!